# Roslyn - dynamic (runtime) flow

Tags: c#, code-coverage, roslyn

I started playing with Roslyn. It’s relatively easy to parse code and do static analysis.

I wonder if it’s possible to use it for runtime analysis? I want to call a method with parameters and check which branches were executed. In other words, I need a runtime execution plan.
Is it something which could be done with Roslyn?

Comment: What's your goal here? You could rewrite a given method to log info about which branches were taken and then run that rewritten method. Would this be acceptable? Or do you *need* to run the actual method and check which branches were executed quickly?

Comment: I would like to write a tool which calculate test coverage so I need to know outcome and what was actually executed (which line of code). The same if any line fails I would like to know it.

Comment: I do the same with il recompilation; basically you wat to increment a static variabele for each branche. Works just fine, so you should be able to do the same based on an ast tree... Ps: code coverage on branch level is IMHO better than on line level.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You mean that I should add unique variable(static) for each branch and then execute code. After that I can just read it and check which variable was set which is the same as checking which branch was executed. I have to admit that it's easy and smart:)

Is it how nCover, nCrunch and other test coverage tools work?

Comment: You're looking for the .Net profiling API.

Comment: Hmm I haven't heard about profiling API.  The solution with static variables + roslyn is also good in my opinion.

What do you think? Which one is more suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the **best** solution is and I would defer to anything SLaks recommends in most cases.

However...

If you want to do this with Roslyn you certainly can. In fact at my company does something similar (we map unit tests to the methods they invoke).

Here's a high level overview of our approach.

1. Rewrite every single function in the solution to log when it is hit in some global static lookup/data-structure. You can iterate over every file one at a time and use the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` on each one. (In your case you'll be rewriting on a branch or line-by-line basis)
2. Run each unit test one at a time and see what gets run by analzying your global lookup.
3. Aggregate the results across all your unit tests to understand your complete code coverage.

Comment: You prefer rewrite each file separately. The reason why I prefer to do it in the way I described in another post is that very often not all classes are covered by unit test. I want to write VS plugin where user can click on a test and it will show what is covered by this particular test. According to the above solution I would have to rewrite all classes even if they are not covered by tests.

Comment: You can definitely do it your way, it may just be challenging to figure out which methods you need to rewrite.

Comment: There's also an open source continuous test framework you may be interested in: https://github.com/continuoustests/ContinuousTests