# Roslyn: SyntaxWalker through 2 different documents

Tags: roslyn

I have a solution with two different projects. I use SyntaxWalker to process some stuff in `ProjectA.Class1`. However, `ProjectA.Class1` has reference `ProjectB.Class2`.

Is there way to allow the syntax walker to traverse also through external classes? I can't even do it when both classes are in the same project but in different files (documents). It always goes through the same document. If both classes are in the same file then it works. If I extract them to separate ones, it doesn't...

I am working on a test coverage tool. A user click on the method in VS and then:

1. I use rewriter to add static variables to each branch.
2. I run the code so the static variables are set if branch was covered.

I wonder how should I configure a syntax walker\rewriter to recognize other classes in the same solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Syntax walkers operate on single documents (single syntax trees). What's your walker trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically I want to analyse code from the entry point. A user gives me a method name and then from this point I want to walk through all references which he has in a solution. Treat it more like code coverage tool or automatic tool which adds some comments into methods and it has to traverse through all users methods (but only the used ones).

I added some comments to the main question above.

Comment: Do you have access to the whole project/solution? Can't you use that to get to the second file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need access to the Symbol API. A simple rule of thumb I try to go by:

- The Syntax API is for individual files
- The Symbol API allows you to work with information that spans across files.

You've mentioned in the comments that you'd like to traverse methods and figure out some information about each method declaration. Here's some (naive) code that should get you started with the symbol API.

I've assumed you've got access to a `Project` that you're analyzing.

```
Project myProject;
public void ProcessMethod(MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
{
    //Get the semantic model
    var filePath = method.SyntaxTree.FilePath;
    var containingDocument = myProject.Documents.Where(n => n.FilePath == filePath).Single();
    var model = containingDocument.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

    //...
    //Do your processing on the current method here...
    //...

    //Process the invoked methods.
    var invocations = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
    foreach(var invocation in invocations)
    {
        var invokedSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol; //Might be null
        var invokedSymbolSyntax = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)invokedSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.First().GetSyntax(); //Partial methods might be declared in multiple places
        ProcessMethod(invokedSymbolSyntax);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- This approach doesn't handle constructors, destructors, properties, expression-bodied members and any other members I've forgotten. But it should be enough to get you started and introduce you to the symbol API.
- Recursion will bite you.
- You won't process implementations of interfaces. You'll have to look into the [`SymbolFinder`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder_Hierarchy.cs,2ff44ec7ffcdbeaf) for that.

Comment: Do you think that CSharpSyntaxRewriter (with the above improvements) and static variables per each branch are reasonable way to calculate the test coverage (in terms of performance)? Are there any faster ways to do it?
I know about recursion but I mean is the general concepts (static varaible) fine?

Comment: My reply isn't going to fit in a comment so I'll draft what I would do as an answer to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958406/roslyn-dynamic-runtime-flow

Comment: I wouldn't use the above when rewriting to discover test coverage, I'd just rewrite every file independently with a `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`